# Baffled with MySQL LEFT JOIN query that I have to speed it up

Tags: mysql, performance, percona-server

I am kind of a puzzled with this query trying to optimize it but no way I am able to (due to my limited knowledge as a DBA). So, I asked the experts.

In my setup I have three (primary) tables. contacts, dnc_contacts (dnc = do not call) and callrequests. I have to select the contacts from contacts table, and copy the contact into callrequests table where contact is not equal to contacts from dnc_contacts. It all looks good so far, but since the data is growing, things are getting slower and slower. The original query I am currently using is:

```
INSERT IGNORE callrequests (contact_id, contact, call_status, campaign_id, phonebook_id, dnc_group_id, created_date, active_call, processed)
SELECT c.id,
       c.contact,
       1,
       '134',
       '70',
       '21',
       '2014-03-14 14:50:58',
       0,
       0
FROM contacts c
LEFT JOIN dnc_contacts d ON c.contact <> d.contact
WHERE phonebook_id = '70' AND d.group_id = '21'
ORDER BY c.id ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE phonebook_id =
VALUES(phonebook_id), dnc_group_id =
VALUES(dnc_group_id), call_status = if(call_status = '2', VALUES(call_status), call_status)
```

This query is taking around 8 minutes and plus to complete depending on the data in contacts and dnc_contacts table. Schema for all these 3 tables is at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ec3a

**Setup**

The setup is a dedicated Xeon machine with 12 cores having 64 GB RAM and 38 GB InnoDB buffer pool size. The DB size is around 6 GB.

Callrequests table has around 5427519 records

Contacts table has around 20498053 records

Dnc_Contacts table has around 4042246 records

Here is the explain output from the select query above,

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------------+------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                    | key  | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------------+------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | ref  | fk_dnc_contact_dnc_group1_idx,v1 | v1   | 4       | const | 2014474 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref  | fk_contact_phonebook1_idx,v1     | v1   | 4       | const | 2218560 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------------+------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------+
```

Is there a way the query can be speed up or maybe if we can change the logic either?

Comment: Tag this to MySQL.

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`? What exactly do you want to do when there are duplicates?

Comment: There are records in the table already so INSERT IGNORE not to insert again, and if found a record, update the call_status of that record.

Comment: You can remove the `IGNORE` then. Not 100% sure but I think the `IGNORE` is ignored.

Comment: Anyway, the real problem is the huge cross join that query creates. That `ON c.contact <> d.contact` looks fishy and it probably does not do what you aim to do.

Comment: I agree with @ypercube. The `ON c.contact <> d.contact` should really be `ON c.contact = d.contact` along with adding `AND d.contact IS NULL` to the `WHERE` clause. The crossjoin will still make mysql take a beating, but you can get more accurate results.

Comment: Results from the original query above are accurate. However the issue is performance. But if I use `ON c.contact = d.contact` along with `AND d.contact IN NULL` along with `d.group_id = ..` in the `WHERE` clause, I don't get any result at all. I also have tried `SELECT DISTINCT contacts.contact FROM contacts LEFT JOIN dnc_contacts USING (contact) WHERE dnc_contacts.contact IS NULL` which works fine but as soon as I introduce any `WHERE` clause in `dnc_contact.group_id = ..` there is no result. So the real emphasis is on the performance, or maybe I should change the schema altogether?

Comment: See my answer. You get no result because you kept the `d.group_id = 21` in the `WHERE` clause. It should go to the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Your query does **not** do what you think it does. It results in much more rows than you want to because of the cross join. The only reason you haven't noticed it, is that the excessive number of rows produced are not really inserted in the 3rd table due to duplicate keys which trigger either the `INSERT IGNORE` or the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

(And you should really keep one of these two, there is absolutely no reason to have both `IGNORE` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. MySQL will either ignore the duplicate keys or try to update the existing row. Does it make sense to ignore someone and talk to him at the same time?)

You probably need:

```
FROM contacts c
  LEFT JOIN dnc_contacts d 
    ON  d.contact = c.contact
    AND d.group_id = 21
WHERE c.phonebook_id = 70 
  AND d.contact IS NULL
```

Try the above (just `SELECT` first, without inserting), to see if it gives you the wanted results.

An index on `dnc_contacts (group_id, contact)` would help with efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your explain statement, it doesn't seem like its using the indexes that you would like it to use. I am not sure what key 'v1' is.

```
WHERE phonebook_id = '70' AND d.group_id = '21'
```

From some of the other questions on SO, there has been a couple comments that say it is possible that MySQL isn't using the correct index because of casting. Try removing the single quotes to see if it allows MySql to use the proper indexes. 'fk_dnc_contact_dnc_group1_idx' and 'fk_contact_phonebook1_idx'.

```
WHERE phonebook_id = 70 AND d.group_id = 21
```